# setting gif image toProgressBar

Tags: android, gif, progressdialog

I have used GIF image to the progress bar using library its working fine but problem is that it doesn't repeat the animation

```
loading_dialog = new ProgressDialog(LeadProfile.this, style.MyInnerProgressDialogTheme);
loading_dialog.setCancelable(false);
loading_dialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(GifDrawable.createFromResource(getResources(), drawable.home_loder));
loading_dialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
        loading_dialog.show();
```

can anybody help me .. i have even used the custom window view and custom dialog it is still not working that is not repeating the animation though the GIF image have that repetition

Comment: you can use sequence of images and use AnimationDrawable for that. you don't need library if you use sequence of images

Comment: Have you tried to call  setLoopCount(0) on your GifDrawable ?

Comment: thanks @Prashant but i have already use library for GIF image and  do not want to use sequence images .

Comment: Yes @KevinLEGOFF I have even tried that actually that looping is working if i am using it in activity layout but if i tried to do it for progress bar then its not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use Animation Drawable instead. 
You will need sequence of images for that(you can create it from gif itself

In your `Activity` or `Dialog`

```
// ImageView that will act as loader. it can be added in `Activity` or `Dialog`
ImageView loading_dialog = (ImageView);
findViewById(R.id.loading_dialog); 

loading_dialog.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.preloader);
AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) loading_dialog.getBackground();
animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) preLoader.getBackground();

// to start animation
animationDrawable.start();

// to stop animation

animationDrawable.stop();
```

And in drawable folder create preloader.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false" >
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/preloader1"
    android:duration="45"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/preloader2"
    android:duration="45"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/preloader3"
    android:duration="45"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/preloader4"
    android:duration="45"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/preloader5"
    android:duration="45"/>
```

if you want to run this only once change `android:oneshot:"true"`
and you can have as many as items you images. and you can change duration for one image too.